# How to make the combination of elements from an array and display on tableView in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have an array like this:-

```
var priceArray = [0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000]
```

I got this data from an Api in my app. And I am using `tableView` to Show data So I can provide the selection of prices like this: -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return priceArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "stickCell", for: indexPath) as! StcikCell
    cell.priceLabel.text = "\(priceArray[0]) - \(priceArray[1])"
    return cell
}
```

But the problem is if I will use this:

```
cell.priceLabel.text = "\(priceArray[0]) - \(priceArray[1])"
```

I will get only the first and second value in `tableView` But what I actually want is in first row I want to get `0 - 200` then in second row `200 - 400` in third `400 - 600` and so on until I will get the combination of `800 - 1000`. How can I do this. Please help?

Comment: Well, replace the indices `0` and `1` by something which depends on `indexPath.row` ...

Comment: You should have `var priceArray = [[0, 200], [200, 400], etc.`. Note that you can construct it from your current `priceArray` definition. Then it will be easier, `let values = priceArray[indexPath.row]; cell.priceLabel.text = "\(values[0]) - \(values[1])"`

Comment: But Sir @Larme don't it be a long process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return (priceArray.count - 1)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "stickCell", for: indexPath) as! StcikCell
    let index = indexPath.row
    cell.priceLabel.text = "\(priceArray[index]) - \(priceArray[index + 1])"
    return cell
}
```

This should do the job.

Comment: because on reaching the last element, code will crash as `(last + 1)` will not be present

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `indexPath.row` to index `priceArray` in `cellForRowAt` and also need to modify `numberOfRowsInSection` since there are less price ranges than the number of elements in `priceArray`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return priceArray.count - 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "stickCell", for: indexPath) as! StcikCell
    cell.priceLabel.text = "\(priceArray[indexPath.row]) - \(priceArray[indexPath.row+1])"
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Why `priceArray.count - 2` ?

Comment: we should use return priceArray.count - 1 
because we are not used  only one value 1000  as first value

Comment: Should be `priceArray.count - 1`

Comment: Perfect now we have 3 similar answers :P

Comment: Hard to choose it then :D

Answer (score 1):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return priceArray.count - 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "stickCell", for: indexPath) as! StcikCell


    cell.priceLabel.text = "\(priceArray[indexPath.row]) - \(priceArray[indexPath.row + 1])"


        return cell
    }
```

Comment: This code will not work as the cell is not being returned when the `if` case fails, it's a compile time error.

Comment: sorry for my mistake, please check my edited answer. @Aakash

Comment: Also for the updated answer the last cell's `priceLabel` label text will not be set, this will not be desirable behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Your price array has 6 elements. but you need 5 price range.
So you need to minus 1 from numberOfRowsInSection, that will give you 5 element.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return priceArray.count - 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "stickCell", for: indexPath) as! StcikCell
    cell.priceLabel.text = "\(priceArray[indexPath.row]) - \(priceArray[indexPath.row+1])"
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create function for creating dataSource array for your tableView:

```
func makeTableDataSource(from priceArray: [Int]) -> [String] {
    var resultArray = [String]()

    for (index, price) in priceArray.enumerated() where index < priceArray.count - 1 {
        resultArray.append("\(price) - \(priceArray [index + 1])")
    }

    return resultArray
}
```

Results of it:

```
    var priceArray = [0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000]

    Result:
    - 0 : "0 - 200"
    - 1 : "200 - 400"
    - 2 : "400 - 600"
    - 3 : "600 - 800"
    - 4 : "800 - 1000"
```

---

```
    var priceArray = [0, 200, 400]

    Result:
    - 0 : "0 - 200"
    - 1 : "200 - 400"
```

---

```
    var priceArray = [0]

    Result:
    []
```

After that, just create property like `private var tableViewDataSource = [String]()`
Then in your `viewDidLoad()` add:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    var priceArray = [0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000] 
    tableViewDataSource = makeTableDataSource(from: priceArray)
}
```

And it's easy to use in your case:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableViewDataSource.count 
} 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "stickCell", for: indexPath) as! StcikCell
    cell.priceLabel.text = tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Pros of this approach:

- you create your data source only once when open viewController
- datasource for your cell not generating "on the fly"
- single responsibility for generating tableDataSource data (if you'll need to update strings, you need todo it only in `makeTableDataSource`, and everything else work fine)
- potentially errors easy to locate
- single "data of trues" for all table (you don't need use `array.count - 1`, or `array.count + 1` in different cases, so less places for potentially crashes)
- and you can reuse this function of course :)

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to prepare dataSource properly.
To do that, I recommend to split existing price array into chunks and map it to objects you want to represent. In your case String type.
You can use following extension:

```
extension Sequence {
func split(by chunkSize: Int) -> [[Self.Element]] {
    return self.reduce(into:[]) { memo, cur in
        if memo.count == 0 {
            return memo.append([cur])
        }
        if memo.last!.count < clump {
            memo.append(memo.removeLast() + [cur])
        } else {
            memo.append([cur])
        }
    }
}
}
```

Usage:

```
var priceArray = [0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000]
let dataSource = priceArray.split(by: 2).map { "\($0[0]) - \($0[1])" }
// result: ["0 - 200", "400 - 600", "800 - 1000"]
```